# Fuerte on Fedora 18: build error at rosbag

Tags: rosbag, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build Fuerte on a Fedora 18 x86_64 system as detailed [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Fedora#preview). In the first make step, it errors out with:

```
$ make -j8
.....
[ 95%] Built target draw_square
[ 95%] Built target mimic
[ 95%] Built target turtle_teleop_key
[ 96%] Built target turtlesim_node
[ 96%] Built target actionlib
[ 96%] [ 97%] Built target drop
Built target rxtools
[ 97%] [ 97%] Built target relay
Built target mux
[ 97%] Built target switch_mux
[ 97%] Built target throttle
[ 97%] [ 97%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o
Built target python_rxtools
[ 98%] Built target rxconsole
[ 98%] Built target rxloggerlevel
/home/ankur/ros-underlay/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp: In member function ‘void rosbag::Recorder::doRecord()’:
/home/ankur/ros-underlay/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp:439:42: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
make[2]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[ankur@dhcppc1  build]$
```

Would anyone know how to correct/workaround this please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58779/fuerte-on-fedora-18:-build-error-at-rosbag/) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue filed here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4022

The following change fixes it and lets it build.

```
+#if BOOST_VERSION >= 105000
+              boost::xtime_get(&xt, boost::TIME_UTC_);
+#else
              boost::xtime_get(&xt, boost::TIME_UTC);
+#endif
```

---

Originally posted by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) with karma: 128 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DirtyWork](https://answers.ros.org/users/25067/dirtywork/) on 2015-11-12**:
I think I have the same problem, into what file this change should be applied?